# Retrieve result with the suggested keyword automatically with solr

Tags: solr, spell-checking

is it possible to get the results using the suggested keyword by spell checker. 
For example, when I search for `whar`, solr correctly suggests `wharf`, but is it possible to get the results for `wharf` in the same request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can define the Solr spellchecker settings in the request handler to get the spell suggestion with the response itself.

```
<requestHandler name="custom_handler" class="solr.SearchHandler">
   <lst name="defaults">
     <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>

     <!-- Query settings -->
     <str name="defType">edismax</str>
     <str name="qf">
        text^0.5 features^1.0 name^1.2 sku^1.5 id^10.0 manu^1.1 cat^1.4
     </str>
     <str name="q.alt">*:*</str>
     <str name="rows">10</str>
     <str name="fl">*,score</str>

     <!-- Spell checking defaults -->
     <str name="spellcheck">on</str>
     <str name="spellcheck.collate">true</str>
     <str name="spellcheck.onlyMorePopular">false</str>
     <str name="spellcheck.extendedResults">false</str>
     <str name="spellcheck.count">3</str>
   </lst>

   <!-- append spellchecking to our list of components -->
   <arr name="last-components">
     <str>spellcheck</str>
   </arr>
</requestHandler>
```

The request handler can be used with the query with the qt param e.g. `qt=custom_handler`

**EDIT -**
Mistook the question.
This is not possible. you can't get the results and for the spell suggestion in the same call. You would need to requery.

Comment: Hiya, thanks for the response. Could you tell me which bit in this configuration defines the response setting you mentioned above? Also what does spellcheck.count does?

Comment: But this doesn't fetch the query results using the suggestions. I don't think it's possible.

Comment: I agree with @MauricioScheffer you cannot fetch the query results using the suggestions returned in the same query. However, it would be an option to examine the results, check for any results and then if needed use the collation value to issue a second query using the collation value as the new query terms.

Comment: So it's not possible to get the result for the suggested keyowrd in one request.

Comment: I got it wrong. I thought getting results and spell in same call. @Maurico and Paige are right ... you can't do it.

Comment: Thanks for the update. What happens then, do i still need to accept this as an answer?

Comment: nope ... it doesn't answer your question .... you should not accept it. Would delete it as the question was misunderstood

Comment: I think it would be good to keep it here so next person can see the answer.

Comment: Actually could you answer this question saying it can't be done,so I can accept that answer?